# Condition for zero or non-zero bias under transformation of random variable?

Tags: random-variable, expected-value

Suppose $\epsilon$ is a zero-mean univariate random variable noise with finite variance. I would like to find the condition on the function $f$ so that:

$$ \exists x \in R \  \mbox{s.t:} \mathbb{E}[f(x +\epsilon)] \neq f(x ) $$

You can assume differentiability on $f$ if necessary.

Comment: If there is no such $x,$ then $E[f(x+\epsilon)]=f(x)$ everywhere.  One definition of a *convex function* is that $E[f(x+\epsilon)]\ge f(x)$ for *any* random variable $\epsilon.$  Thus, if $f$ is an exception to your criterion, then both $f$ and $-f$ are convex functions.  You should have no trouble proceeding from there.  Notice that neither differentiability of $f$ nor finite variance of $\epsilon$ are needed. It is important, though, that $\Pr(\epsilon=0)\ne 1$ and that $f$ be measurable.

Answer (score 1):

Answered in comment:

> If there is no such $x,$ then $E[f(x+\epsilon)]=f(x)$ everywhere.  One
> definition of a *convex function* is that $E[f(x+\epsilon)]\ge f(x)$
> for *any* random variable $\epsilon.$  Thus, if $f$ is an exception to
> your criterion, then both $f$ and $-f$ are convex functions.  You
> should have no trouble proceeding from there.  Notice that neither
> differentiability of $f$ nor finite variance of $\epsilon$ are needed.
> It is important, though, that $\Pr(\epsilon=0)\ne 1$ and that $f$ be
> measurable.

– whuber